# Using sp_ as prefix for user stored procedures in SQL server causing performance impact

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We are using SQL Server 2014 SP2 CU4. What is the performance impact of having the user defined stored procedures prefixed with `sp_` instead of `usp_`? How can it be quantified, since we are unable to measure the impact using the sql profiling tools.

I read on this link, that it does have an impact:

https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `sp_` prefix is reserved for system stored procedures. It should not be used for user stored procedures. Even though you have a local stored proc with `sp_` prefix, SQL Server will check master database first.

This has been covered in depth by Aaron Bertrand here: [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Quote from article on impact:

> The performance issue comes from the fact that master might be checked for an equivalent stored procedure, depending on whether there is a local version of the procedure, and whether there is in fact an equivalent object in master. This can lead to extra metadata overhead as well as an additional SP:CacheMiss event.

He also did some tests, below are the results:

[image]