# TSQL: Using 'Output' clause in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using an `Output` clause in my `Insert` statement which requires use of a `Table Variable`. I also want the `Table name` to be dynamic so I'm using `dynamic SQL` but it won't allow use of a `Table Variable`. I get the error `Must declare the scalar variable "@InsertedId"`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertPerson @Name varchar(50), @Table varchar(20) AS
  DECLARE @InsertedId TABLE (Id int)
  DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(200) = 'INSERT INTO ' + @Table + ' (Name) OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO ' + @InsertedId + ' VALUES (' + @Name + ')'
  IF (@Name is not null AND @Name != '')
    EXEC(@SQL)
  SELECT Id FROM @InsertedId
```

How can I both use the `Output` clause and a dynamic `Table name`

Comment: Try my answer below.

Comment: Your path leads to doom. Go back before it's too late. SQL is a declarative language. So your code should follow the paradigm enforced by the engine and language. It is unlikely (and logically invalid) for a "person" to exist in different tables as this means your schema is not properly normalized. I suggest you completely rethink your schema and how you intend to approach interfacing with it from your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, do not use **[`sp_`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640852/using-sp-as-prefix-for-user-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-causing-performance)** prefix to your stored procedure, cause it reserved to System stored procedures by MS, and can lead to performance issue and other problems (as it can be a habit). Use **[`SysName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** datatype for the table name, and use **[`QUOTENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function when you concatenate the string.

You need to declare your table in the DynamicSQL as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertPerson 
@Name varchar(50), 
@Table SysName
AS
  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @SQL = N'DECLARE @IDs TABLE (ID INT);'+
             'INSERT INTO ' + 
             QUOTENAME(@Table) + 
             ' (Name) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @IDs VALUES(@Name);'+
             'SELECT * FROM @IDs';
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL,
                        N'@Name VARCHAR(50)',
                        @Name;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=15e5665641fcda17370b2be55edfdebe)**

Comment: The `DECLARE @IDs TABLE(ID INT);` after `AS` and `= @Name` at the end are not needed.  Edit your answer and I'll mark it as the answer. Please let me know if there is a reason you included them.

Comment: @Joe The last line `@Name = @Name;` is needed if you going to pass the Name as a parameter instead of concatenate it as `VALUES('''+@Name+''');'`

Comment: I edited your db<>fiddle to remove ` = @Name` and it works fine (`EXEC dbo.InsertPerson 'B', 'T';`)

Comment: @Joe Since the param of the SP is the same it will work, but if you have another name it won't work, so for this you can remove it

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertPerson @Name varchar(50), @Table varchar(20) AS

  DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(200) = ''  
  SET @SQL = @SQL + 'DECLARE @InsertedId TABLE (Id int)';      
  SET @SQL = @SQL + 'INSERT INTO ' + @Table + ' (Name) OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @InsertedId (Id) VALUES (''' + @Name + ''')'    
  SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT Id FROM @InsertedId'
  IF (@Name is not null AND @Name != '')
    EXEC(@SQL)
```

---

Comment: I edited your answer to add single quotes, you need two sets of three single quotes. `VALUES (''' + @Name + ''')'`.  It's all about the scope huh.  So why are the scalar variables in scope but not the table variable?