# How to execute SQL string from C#, and store the returned result in a DataTable, or some other appropriate data structure?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a string that returns a number of records when executed via `SQL Server Management Studio`:

```
  EXEC stored_proc1 '2019-05-20';// Returns certain record on executing
  EXEC stored_proc2 '2019-05-20','ABC'; // Returns certain record on executing
  EXEC stored_proc3 '2019-05-20', true, 'DEF';// Returns certain record on executing
```

Need to write the results of each of the above statements to different CSV files. I need a generic solution that is independent of what parameters are passed to the stored proc and store the result of executing the statement in an appropriate data structure (maybe DataTable?) which I can then parse and write the data to different CSV files.
Tried using `SQLDataAdapter`and storing the result in a `DataTable` but couldn't make it work.

```
var connectionString = "my connection string";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_return_records '2019-05-20','ABC';", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
            using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                a.Fill(t1);
            }
```

Not sure if this is the correct way of executing the string. I am getting System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Execution Timeout Expired.

Comment: Hi, you will need to be more specific than "couldnt make it work" .. what code did you use, what results did you get, what problem did you have

Comment: Can you provide example?

Comment: Have edited the question and added the code I wrote that didn't work

Comment: You pass a SQL query to SqlCommand and yet you specify that `CommandType` is a stored procedure *name*. Pass only the name to SqlCommand. The parameters should be added to SqlCommand's Parameters collection.

Comment: Yes it didn't feel right to me either so I knew it wouldn't work. 
What's the correct way of executing a query and storing the result.
Removed the

Comment: See I removed the CommandType stored procedure, now getting a different error, Execution Timeout Expired.

I don't wish to add the parameters, because I need to execute different stored procedures this way which all have different number of parameters. I want the code to return records and store them, irrespective of which SP name is mentioned in the command string.

Comment: @chickenmomo the approach of embedding parameters in a string is usually a **terrible idea** - it might be OK if these are hard-coded or configuration-supplied trusted strings, but if that data comes from your app executing, **seriously, don't do that** - it will hurt you *a lot*. Parameters are your friend, and tools like "Dapper" exist to make working with parameters a painless experience. Additional notes: the `sp_` prefix is reserved by Microsoft - you're not meant to prefix your own procs with that; and you should *almost never* use `DataTable` these days.

Comment: I have multiple stored procedures that return records. The different SPs accept different parameters, that's why I am looking for a generic solution that executes a string with hard coded parameters and returns the result in some data structure, that can be easily parsed and written to a CSV

Answer (score 1):

```cs
List<MyKnownType> rows;
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    DateTime when = ... /// 2019-05-20 - typed **as a DateTime**, not a string
    rows = conn.Query<MyKnownType>("return_records",
        new { ParamNameHere = when, AnotherParamName = "ABC" }, // this is the parameters
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
    ).AsList();
}
```

Important points here:

- `DataTable` is almost never a preferred choice, unless you're writing a dynamic reporting app, or something similar to SSMS
- in this case, I'm using a `class MyKnownType { ... }` which would have properties that match your expected columns in both name and type
- parameters; always parameters
- ADO.NET has an unfriendly API; tools like "Dapper", shown above, make it easy
- I removed the `sp_` prefix; [you aren't meant to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640852/using-sp-as-prefix-for-user-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-causing-performance)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;

public class Car
{
    public string Model{ get; set; }
    public string Color{ get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

var sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.Append(" SELECT Model, Color, Year ");
sql.Append(" FROM   TableCar ");

var list = someDBCONTEXT.Database.SqlQuery<Car>(sql.ToString()).ToList();
```

Important points here:

I'm using Entity Framework 6

Comment: You should probably be explicit about what tools are in play here; this looks like it might be EF or EF-Core?