# Stored procedure always returns 0, even if the process inside works fine

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure for deleting data. It should delete a program only if no field is connected to that program.

My logic is to count columns related to `TA_Program` by Id first, and if count returns 0 then delete the program, if returns -3 then alert for field connection, and else for alert for internet connection.

However, even if the deleting process itself works well, the stored procedure always returns 0 so that alert for failure I made always come up.

I read several posts about `@@ROWCOUNT`, relationship between `delete` and `ROWCOUNT`, but every try returned 0, nothing else. Would you please give me help to solve this problem?

This is my stored procedure and how it is queried.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Delete_Program_By_Id 
    (@Id int)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FieldCount AS int
    DECLARE @ResultCount AS int
    
    -- count FieldId Where Id = @Id
    SELECT @FieldCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TA_Field (Nolock) WHERE Id = @Id)
       
    -- if no Field is connected, delete program
    IF @FieldCount = 0
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM TA_Program
        WHERE Id = @Id

        SELECT @FieldCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TA_Program (Nolock) WHERE Id = @Id)

        IF @FieldCount = 0
            SELECT @ResultCount = 1
        ELSE
            SELECT @ResultCount = -1
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT @ResultCount = -3

    RETURN @ResultCount
END
```

C# code:

```
    public static int DeleteProgram(Program obj)
    {
        int result = -1;

        // Sort is for determining db id and pw stored 
        using (var db = DBConnectionHelper.GetConnection(Sort.Program))
        {
            var param = new DynamicParameters();
            //param.Add("@FieldId", obj.FieldId);
            param.Add("@Id", obj.Id, dbType: DbType.Int32);
            result = db.Query<int>("APISP_Delete_Program_By_Id", param: param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault<int>();
        }

        return result;
        // this always returns 0
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public APIResult DeleteProgram(string session, Program program)
    {
        int deleteResult = ProgramsDbHelper.DeleteProgram(program);

        if (deleteResult == 1)
        {
            result.ResultCode = 1;
            return result;
        }

        if (deleteResult == -3)
        {
            result.ResultCode = -3;
            return result;
        }            

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us how you are calling the SP and accessing the return value.

Comment: @Dale K I added some codes, thanks!

Comment: You don't appear be to adding a return parameter? Which is how you access the return value. For SingleOrDefault you would need to `select @ResultCount` rather than return it.

Comment: Stop spamming your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Made worse by using deprecated syntax.

Comment: your defined procedure and the one you are calling in C# are different names: APISP_Delete_Program_By_Id (program call) , SP_Delete_Program_By_Id (procedure definition)

Comment: please refrain from prefixing your stored procedures with sp_ it does not actually stand for "stored procedure". SP_ is used by system stored procedures - see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640852/using-sp-as-prefix-for-user-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-causing-performance

Comment: Good day @MovingRootLee, In order to reproduce your scenario we need you to provide queries to create the relevant table(s) and to insert some sample data. Using this sample data explain which information you try to delete and what behave not as you request

Comment: I really appereciate all of you for every advice! I was confused with `return` and `select` , as I changed to `select @ResultCount` as @Dale K and now everything works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your procedure has a number of issues**

- Your primary issue: **using `RETURN` instead of `SELECT`**
- Use of `NOLOCK` should be avoided
- Use of `sp_` prefix should be avoided
- Assuming `TA_Field` is foreign-keyed to `TA_Program`, the logic doesn't make sense: because you have no transaction and are not using `HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK`, it is possible for another user to insert into `TA_Program` in between your `SELECT COUNT` and `DELETE`, at which point you will get an error, and the rest of the procedure will not run. If no-one inserted then the extra `SELECT COUNT` is useless, because the data hasn't changed.
- You don't actually need any of that logic, because you can combine it in the `DELETE` statement (every statement is in its own transaction anyway).

So your procedure should look like this instead:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Delete_Program_By_Id 
    (@Id int)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DELETE FROM TA_Program
WHERE Id = @Id
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM TA_Field
      WHERE Id = @Id);
  
SELECT CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN 1 ELSE -3 END;

GO
```